# How to connect to wifi from single-user mode?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, mac

the `en0` wireless interface doesnt seem to be available from the terminal. is it possible to connect to known and/or new wifi hotspots from the single-user mode console?

```
root# ifconfig -a
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280

root# networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 <SSID> '<wifi password>'
Error obtaining SC session.
All Wi-Fi network services are disabled.
```

my specifications:

```
sh-3.2# system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: OS X 10.8.5 (12F45)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 12.5.0
      Boot Volume: lily
      Boot Mode: Normal
      Computer Name: lily’s MacBook Air
      User Name: System Administrator (root)
      Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
      Time since boot: 12:37
```

Comment: What's the purpose of enabling Wi-Fi in SU mode? In contrary to Maurice's answer I think it's possible to accomplish this. But you have to load a lot of daemons and agents in the proper sequence so that it's easier to boot normally.

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge this is not possible as the necessary services/daemons that enable networking don‘t start in single user mode.